# Layouting the index-page

Tags: formatting, indexing

I'm using `\printindex` for my index and I wonder how to have

1. bold page numbers
2. ordering by first character of the indexed word and have dots
   in between the name and page number like

> A
>   Apple .... 1
>   Always ... 5
>
> B
>   Bottle ... 2
>   Beauty ... 7

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm assuming that your index was generated with the help of the `makeindex` program. This program is automatically called when you compile a LaTeX document with makefiles like `latexmk` and may also be called by editors like TeXworks or TeXnicCenter. The output generated by `makeindex` can be configured by using an `.ist` style file. Details about creating such a file can be found e.g. in section 11.2 of the *LaTeX Companion*. The following example file would create bold headings for each index letter group and add dots between index keywords and page numbers.

```
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\bfseries "
heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak\n"
delim_0 " \\dotfill "
delim_1 " \\dotfill "
delim_2 " \\dotfill "
```

To use the file, save it as `mystyle.ist` and call `makeindex` with the parameter

```
-s mystyle.ist
```

when compiling your LaTeX document. How to exactly add this parameter depends on your compilation method. As a quick workaround: If your main document is called `<name>.tex`, save the above file as `<name>.mst` (note the different file type!), copy it to your working directory and compile `<name>.tex` as usual.

Note that there is a package called [`idxlayout`](http://ctan.org/pkg/idxlayout) (disclosure: I'm the package author). This package acts as a complement to `.ist` files for configuring index layout
parameters, e. g. allowing for three-column indexes or for "parent" items and
their affiliated subitems being typeset as a single paragraph.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! As I use TexnicCenter, I could define the option "-s stylefile.ist" for my compilation-profile easily! Works great!!

Comment: Could you please explain me how to make the font of the main-items bold? Tried it with `item_0 "\n \\bf{\\item}"` but this makes also the dots, the page number and the subitems bold...

Comment: This works also with sections, i.e. `heading_prefix "{\\section*{"`, in order to have consistent formatting with bibliographies grouped by initial letters, like here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150068/how-to-split-the-bibliography-alphabetically

Comment: I have a similar problem, but I have to use imakeidx as there are two indices in the book I am typesetting. As I don't have to explcitly call makeindex, I am not sure how I can include the style file. I tried adding it as an option alongwith \usepackage{makeindex} in the preamble, but that doesn't seem to work. Knowing tex, I am sure there will be a way this can be done, but I don't know that. Thanks in advance for any help in the matter.