# Problem in sorting the index?

Tags: indexing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Layouting the index-page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17213/layouting-the-index-page)

I am writing my master thesis using Latex and I have a problem in sorting the index.

The problem is that I am not able to divide the index into letter groups, and symbol groups. I want the groups to be separated by a capital letter that describes the group.

My system is win.7 64 bit, my distributor is MikTeX 2.9, and my text editor is TeXmaker

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You could try creating a `mystyle.ist` file and add `headings_flag 1` to it, then call `makeindex -s mystyle mydoc.idx`. `:)`

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17213/layouting-the-index-page

Comment: Can you tell me how can I do this ?

And thanks a lot for your quick answer :)

Comment: Please I need your help :)

Comment: @Muhammad Use my answer to the question linked above; however, in your `.ist`/`.mst` file, remove the lines starting with `delim`.

Comment: @ lockstep 

Thanks a lot for your interest :) 

I have read the documentation of the "imakeidx" package and it contains the solution of the problem :) 

Thanks again :)