# How to split the bibliography alphabetically?

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I am using `biblatex` (with `biber`) and I am currently writing a `book` class document. I will have a long bibliography at the end of the document.

Inside this bibliography I would like to have alphabetical sections (A, B, C, ...). The purpose is to help someone who is looking for a reference; he can visualize that he is inside G section (for example). This is the kind of layout that dictionaries have.

Here is an visual attempt to show what I want to achieve:

```
**A** (Big "A" with a size of a section)

Author1 , ...
  --, ...
  --, ...
Author2, ...
.
.
.

**B** (Big "B")

Bauthor1, ...
  --, ...
Bauthor2, ...
  --, ...
.
. 
.
```

Of course, I can add keywords to my `.bib` file and say to BibLaTeX to print all references with keywords "A" inside a section "A". But it sounds stupid to add keywords just for alphabetical section sorting.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,hyperref,backend=biber,isbn=false,doi=false,url=false]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bib}
\title{}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\nocite* 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

`.bib` file:

```
@InBook{arwez_title_2000,
  author =   {Paul Arwez},
  title =    {Title},
  chapter =      {Chapter},
  publisher =    {Publisher},
  year =     2000}

@Book{arwez_book_2013,
  author =   {Paul Arwez},
  title =    {Book},
  publisher =    {Publisher},
  year =     2013}

@Book{barwez_book_2013,
  author =   {Paul Barwez},
  title =    {Book},
  publisher =    {Publisher},
  year =     2013}

@Book{carwez_book_2013,
  author =   {Paul Carwez},
  title =    {Book},
  publisher =    {Publisher},
  year =     2013}

@Article{carwez_artic_1873,
  author =   {Paul Carwez},
  title =    {Article},
  journal =      {Journal},
  year =     1876}
```

`.bbl` file:

```
% $ biblatex auxiliary file $
% $ biblatex bbl format version 2.2 $
% Do not modify the above lines!
%
% This is an auxiliary file used by the 'biblatex' package.
% This file may safely be deleted. It will be recreated by
% biber as required.
%
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{ver@biblatex.sty}
  {\@latex@error
     {Missing 'biblatex' package}
     {The bibliography requires the 'biblatex' package.}
      \aftergroup\endinput}
  {}
\endgroup


\refsection{0}
  \sortlist{entry}{nyt}
    \entry{arwez_title_2000}{inbook}{}
      \name{labelname}{1}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=378583d49d9a8ada29208d6cb5267d5f}{Arwez}{A\bibinitperiod}{Paul}{P\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \name{author}{1}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=378583d49d9a8ada29208d6cb5267d5f}{Arwez}{A\bibinitperiod}{Paul}{P\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \list{publisher}{1}{%
        {Publisher}%
      }
      \strng{namehash}{378583d49d9a8ada29208d6cb5267d5f}
      \strng{fullhash}{378583d49d9a8ada29208d6cb5267d5f}
      \field{sortinit}{A}
      \field{labelyear}{2000}
      \field{labeltitle}{Title}
      \field{chapter}{Chapter}
      \field{title}{Title}
      \field{year}{2000}
    \endentry
    \entry{arwez_book_2013}{book}{}
      \name{labelname}{1}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=378583d49d9a8ada29208d6cb5267d5f}{Arwez}{A\bibinitperiod}{Paul}{P\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \name{author}{1}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=378583d49d9a8ada29208d6cb5267d5f}{Arwez}{A\bibinitperiod}{Paul}{P\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \list{publisher}{1}{%
        {Publisher}%
      }
      \strng{namehash}{378583d49d9a8ada29208d6cb5267d5f}
      \strng{fullhash}{378583d49d9a8ada29208d6cb5267d5f}
      \field{sortinit}{A}
      \field{labelyear}{2013}
      \field{labeltitle}{Book}
      \field{title}{Book}
      \field{year}{2013}
    \endentry
    \entry{barwez_book_2013}{book}{}
      \name{labelname}{1}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=d0455efa6586ff2338c954fc0860f0d2}{Barwez}{B\bibinitperiod}{Paul}{P\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \name{author}{1}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=d0455efa6586ff2338c954fc0860f0d2}{Barwez}{B\bibinitperiod}{Paul}{P\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \list{publisher}{1}{%
        {Publisher}%
      }
      \strng{namehash}{d0455efa6586ff2338c954fc0860f0d2}
      \strng{fullhash}{d0455efa6586ff2338c954fc0860f0d2}
      \field{sortinit}{B}
      \field{labelyear}{2013}
      \field{labeltitle}{Book}
      \field{title}{Book}
      \field{year}{2013}
    \endentry
    \entry{carwez_artic_1873}{article}{}
      \name{labelname}{1}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=baa123e8e737243bb6575c9b2955a321}{Carwez}{C\bibinitperiod}{Paul}{P\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \name{author}{1}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=baa123e8e737243bb6575c9b2955a321}{Carwez}{C\bibinitperiod}{Paul}{P\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \strng{namehash}{baa123e8e737243bb6575c9b2955a321}
      \strng{fullhash}{baa123e8e737243bb6575c9b2955a321}
      \field{sortinit}{C}
      \field{labelyear}{1876}
      \field{labeltitle}{Article}
      \field{journaltitle}{Journal}
      \field{title}{Article}
      \field{year}{1876}
    \endentry
    \entry{carwez_book_2013}{book}{}
      \name{labelname}{1}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=baa123e8e737243bb6575c9b2955a321}{Carwez}{C\bibinitperiod}{Paul}{P\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \name{author}{1}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=baa123e8e737243bb6575c9b2955a321}{Carwez}{C\bibinitperiod}{Paul}{P\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \list{publisher}{1}{%
        {Publisher}%
      }
      \strng{namehash}{baa123e8e737243bb6575c9b2955a321}
      \strng{fullhash}{baa123e8e737243bb6575c9b2955a321}
      \field{sortinit}{C}
      \field{labelyear}{2013}
      \field{labeltitle}{Book}
      \field{title}{Book}
      \field{year}{2013}
    \endentry
  \endsortlist
\endrefsection
\endinput
```

Comment: Do you use the `alpha` style bib keys like `[Aut05]`? Then it should be quite doable with `bibtex`.

Comment: I am using authoryear-comp style. And my bib keys are defined by zotero and look like `author_title_year`? But perhaps what works for alpha styles work also for authoryear ones. I just have no idea how to do it even with alpha style.

Comment: Could you please add a short typical `.bbl` file? (That's the file produced by `bibtex`.) Having that, I will quite surely manage to make a solution ;)

Comment: @tohecz I updated my question with a MWE and a .bbl file.

Comment: Oh you use `biblatex`, **please specify such important thing very clearly in the question next time.** I don't know whether my solution works with `biblatex`, and I have little experience with it to be able to modify it accordingly.

Comment: @tohecz Sorry for your time (but I specified "biblatex" in the first sentence, fourth word...). Unfortunately, your solution seems not working for biblatex.

Comment: Yeah, and added [tag:bibtex] tag to the question. Nevermind.

Comment: @tohecz oups, sorry...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can create a category for each letter in the alphabet and, with `\AtDataInput`, add entries to each category on the basis of the `sortinit` field.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\nocite{angenendt,bertram,doody,gillies}

% user-level test for skipbib enabled (e.g. related entry matuz:doody)
\makeatletter
\def\ifskipbib{\iftoggle{blx@skipbib}}
\makeatother

\def\initlist{}
\forcsvlist{\listadd\initlist}{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z}
\forlistloop{\DeclareBibliographyCategory}{\initlist}
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\defbibheading{#1}{\section*{#1}}}
\dolistloop{\initlist}
\AtDataInput{\ifskipbib{}{\addtocategory{\thefield{sortinit}}{\thefield{entrykey}}}}

\begin{document}
\printbibheading
\bibbycategory
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that we need to access some internals to avoid entries that are skipped in the bibliography. I keep forgetting to make these toggle values available to the user, but we'll get around to it soon.

Comment: Very nice solution which works well.

Comment: I suggest a little modification. If you use the entry `vangennep`, you will get a small `v`. So you can use something like this: `\AtDataInput{%
  \ifskipbib{}
    {%
    \edef\@tempa{\thefield{sortinit}}%
    \uppercase\expandafter{\expandafter\def\expandafter\@tempb\expandafter{\@tempa}}%
    \addtocategory{\@tempb}{\thefield{entrykey}}
  }%
}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Thanks for catching that. The backend should generate an uppercase letter for the `sortinit` field, so this is a biber bug. It is already fixed in the dev release.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work for author names whose first letter is an accented character? I get `! Package biblatex Error: Category '\IeC {\r A}' not declared.` when I use the entry `author = {\r{A}gren, J. Arvid}`.

Comment: @sudosensei Use biber or override the `sortinit` value with another field - say `usera = {A}`. `sortinit` will be changing with new (biber-only) features and its construction under BibTeX could use some improvement. So I won't get around to making this answer more comprehensive till those changes are released.

Comment: I see. No problem. But just in case there's an easy work-around: (a) I am already using biber; and (b) could you please elaborate on what you mean by overriding the `sortinit` value?. No worries if this is the type of change you want to avoid until the changes are released. Thanks.

Comment: @sudosensei (a) I can't see how you could get that error with biber, especially a newer version. (b) Make use of the `usera` field in your bib file and in the hook put, `\iffieldundef{usera}{\addtocategory{\thefield{sortinit}}{\thefield{entrykey}}}{\addtocategory{\thefield{usera}}{\thefield{entrykey}}}}`.

Comment: @Audrey: Thanks for your help. I have found that the issue was caused by the use of `utf8` with the `inputenc` package: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. The document compiles without error if I remove that line. As to whether that is the expected behaviour, I have no idea.

Comment: @sudosensei You need to use the `bibencoding` setting if you want to mix your `tex` and `bib` encodings. Refer to "specifying encodings" in the manual.

Answer (score 13):

Here a hack of the internal `bibitem`:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\def\blx@head@tempa{0}
\def\blx@bibitem#1{%
  \blx@ifdata{#1}
    {\begingroup
     \blx@getdata{#1}%
     \blx@imc@iffieldequals{sortinit}\blx@head@tempa{}{\item[]\textbf{\thefield{sortinit}}}%
       \global\let\blx@head@tempa\abx@field@sortinit%
     \blx@bibcheck
       \global\let\blx@noitem\@empty
     \iftoggle{blx@skipentry}{}{%
       \blx@setoptions@type\abx@field@entrytype
       \blx@setoptions@entry
       \blx@thelabelnumber
       \blx@addprefixnumber
       \addtocounter{instcount}\@ne
       \csuse{blx@item@\blx@theenv}\relax
       \blx@initsep
       \blx@namesep
       \csuse{blx@hook@bibitem}%
       \blx@execute
       \blx@initunit
       \blx@anchor
       \blx@beglangbib
       \bibsentence
       \blx@pagetracker
       \blx@driver\abx@field@entrytype
       \blx@postpunct
       \blx@endlangbib}%
     \endgroup}
    {}}
\makeatother
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: seeing the code, I start to understand why it's (almost) impossible to make biblatex do what you want;) However, this seems to be the only working solution, so +1

Comment: This solution does not work for me. I obtain double letters (AA, BB, CC, ...) before every references.

Comment: I get errors with it... BTW you forgot `\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}`

Comment: @ppr: Did you try the example. I forgot a important line (see comment above)

Comment: I pasted the code inside `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` to my .tex file (so the missing line is not the problem). I was unable to compile without errors and the result is not correct (double AA, BB). I can upload my file in the chat if you want?

Comment: After update biblatex, it is working without error. Now I'm wondering how to put the letters in a bigger size and with more space between them.

Answer (score 12):

Although the marking of alphabetical sections with "heading letters" is sometimes used for indexes, I have never encountered such letters in bibliographies. I suggest to only add extra spacing between alphabetical sections; with `biblatex`, this can be done by simply setting the `\bibinitsep` length to a positive value.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\setlength{\bibinitsep}{\baselineskip}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{A02,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {And now for something completely different},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is a good workaround and it works well. I will wait if there is another answer with sections (A, B, C) and, if not, accept this one.

Answer (score 11):

As biblatex is able to insert a space (\bibinitsep) between this entries, it should also be possible to enter text at this places. The main problem is that we are in a list and so getting the correct spacing and identation is a bit problematic:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,hyperref,backend=biber,isbn=false,doi=false,url=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\title{}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\bibsection{\@startsection {section}{1}{-\leftmargin}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}

\bibinitsep=1pt %to trigger blx@initsep
\def\blx@initsep{%
  \blx@imc@iffieldundef{sortinit}
    {}
    {\ifnum\c@instcount>\@ne
       \blx@imc@iffieldequals{sortinit}\blx@previnit
         {}
         {\bibsection*{\printfield{sortinit}}\item}%instead of \addvspace
     \fi
     \global\let\blx@previnit\abx@field@sortinit}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\nocite*
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Disclaimer: This is a work-around, not a solution.**

You could use `biblatex`'s ability to filter bibliographic entries according to the `keywords` field to do this. All you need to do is add `keywords = {<letter>}` to every bibliographic entry, and `\printbibliography[keyword=<letter>]` will do the rest for you:

[image: Output]

I had to use my bibliography because yours wouldn't display correctly (not sure why). Also, `\bibliography{<file>}` is deprecated now, so I replaced it with `\addbibresource{<file>.ext}`. See the example below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@Article{a:agrawal:2001:01,
  title         = {Phenotypic Plasticity in the Interactions and Evolution of Species},
  author        = {Agrawal, Anurag A.},
  journal       = {Science},
  year          = {2001},
  month         = oct,
  volume        = {294},
  number        = {5541},
  pages         = {321--326},
  doi           = {10.1126/science.1060701},
  url           = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1060701},
  keywords      = {A},
}

@Article{a:auld:2010:01,
  title         = {Re-evaluating the Costs and Limits of Adaptive Phenotypic Plasticity},
  author        = {Auld, Josh R. and Agrawal, Anurag A. and Relyea, Rick A.},
  journal       = {Proceedings of the Royal Society B: Biological Sciences},
  year          = {2010},
  month         = feb,
  volume        = {277},
  number        = {1681},
  pages         = {503--511},
  doi           = {10.1098/rspb.2009.1355},
  url           = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1098/rspb.2009.1355},
  keywords      = {A},
}

@Article{a:brown:2013:01,
  title         = {What Evolvability Really Is},
  author        = {Brown, Rachael L.},
  journal       = {The British Journal for the Philosophy of Science},
  year          = {2013},
  month         = aug,
  doi           = {10.1093/bjps/axt014},
  url           = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/bjps/axt014},
  keywords      = {B},
}

@Article{a:clune:2013:01,
  title         = {The Evolutionary Origins of Modularity},
  author        = {Clune, Jeff and Mouret, Jean-Baptiste and Lipson, Hod},
  journal       = {Proceedings of the Royal Society B: Biological Sciences},
  year          = {2013},
  month         = mar,
  volume        = {280},
  number        = {1755},
  doi           = {10.1098/rspb.2012.2863},
  url           = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1098/rspb.2012.2863},
  keywords      = {C},
}

@Article{a:dias:2013:01,
  title         = {Parental Olfactory Experience Influences Behavior and Neural Structure in Subsequent Generations},
  author        = {Dias, Brian G. and Ressler, Kerry J.},
  journal       = {Nature Neuroscience},
  publisher     = {Nature Publishing Group},
  year          = {2013},
  month         = dec,
  volume        = {},
  number        = {},
  pages         = {1546--1726},
  doi           = {10.1038/nn.3594},
  url           = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nn.3594},
  keywords      = {D},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,hyperref,backend=biber,isbn=false,doi=false,url=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\title{}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
% \printbibliography
\printbibliography[keyword=A,title={A},heading=subbibliography]
\printbibliography[keyword=B,title={B},heading=subbibliography]
\printbibliography[keyword=C,title={C},heading=subbibliography]
\printbibliography[keyword=D,title={D},heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also, using `biblatex` and `biber`, if you always could be sure that the first character of the `author` field was the same as the letter that entry needed to be under, you could automatically add the `keyword` field using `\DeclareSourcemap`.

Comment: @PLK: Nice idea.

Comment: @sudosensei: You can use a loop to simplify it: `\makeatletter
\count@=0
\loop\ifnum\count@<26
  \advance\count@\@ne
  \DeclareBibliographyCategory{\@Alph\count@}
\repeat
\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{\thefield{sortinit}}{\thefield{entrykey}}}\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}`
and `\makeatletter
\count@=0
\loop\ifnum\count@<26
  \advance\count@\@ne
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\printbibliography[category=\@Alph\count@,title={\@Alph\count@},heading=subbibliography]}\x
\repeat
\makeatletter`

Comment: @PLK: I tried: `\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype = bibtex]{
     \map[overwrite=true]{
       \step[fieldsource = sortinit ]
       \step[fieldset = keywords , origfieldval ,append]
      }
  }
}` But it doesn't work? Do I miss something?

Comment: I was aware of this solution but I would like to save me the pain to add a keyword to each reference.

Comment: @PLK I wasn't aware of that. Thanks. @MarcoDaniel I figured there was a way to automate the `printbibliography` commands, but I'm a complete `LaTeX` n00b. So thanks. @OP: You could use the `\DeclareSourcemap` to do that for you as PLK said. But I can see that there are vastly superior answer to your question than mine.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel - `sortinit` isn't a .bib field and sourcemapping works at the .bib level. You'd have to do a regexp match and extract the first character of the author (assuming it was Last, First) and put that in `keywords` - there are examples in the `biber` manual.

Answer (score 5):

*I give a **`bibtex`** solution, in case someone looks for it.*

Well, you should be able to use the following. The idea is that we (1) assume the optional argument is always given, and (2) assume that the first token/letter of the optional argument is the right thing.

**File `test.tex`:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\let\x@bibitem\bibitem% store original \bibitem
\def\x@getfirst#1#2\endgetfirst{#1}% macro that returns the first letter/token of its argument
\def\x@bibalph{}% previous first letter, initiated to nothing
\def\bibitem[#1]{% new bibitem
  \edef\x@bibalphtest{\x@getfirst#1\endgetfirst}% get the new first letter
  \ifx\x@bibalphtest\x@bibalph\else % if the first letter changed
    \let\x@bibalph\x@bibalphtest% update
    \subsection*{\x@bibalph}% and make the \subsection
  \fi
  \x@bibitem[#1]% start the \bibitem itself
}
\makeatother

\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

**File `test.bbl`:**

```
\begin{thebibliography}{ABC06}

\bibitem[Aut00]{author_00}
Author, 2000.

\bibitem[ABC06]{author_buthor_cuthor_2005}
Author, Buthor, Cuthor, 2005.

\bibitem[But02]{buthor_2002}
Buthor, 2002.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Does not work with biblatex.

Comment: Two questions. First, how might this code be adjusted to make it disregard capitalization? E.g., Dutch surnames freqently start with `de` or `De` (de Vries, De Jong) or with `van` or `Van` (van Gogh, Van der Laan, etc). It would be great if the code didn't treat "van Gogh" and "van der Laan" as starting with different letters of the alphabet. Secondly, how might the code be adjusted to treat "accented" characters to be the same as non-accented characters. E.g., how to make the code think that `{\v C}erne` starts with a `C`? (After all, that's what BibTeX does.) Thanks.

Comment: Just in case what may have prompted these questions, please see the recent query [How to group the bibliography alphabetically, if some surnames start with “accented” characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/417751/5001). If you feel inclined to provide a new answer to that query, that would be fabulous.