# Splitting bibliography alphabetically: how to vertically align margin note?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, marginpar, lengths, raise

**Context:** Since my bibliography is constituted of 200+ entries, I want to add margin-notes at each new letter to split the bibliography alphabetically. (I.e., print a "B" in the margin next to the first entry whose author's name starts with B, etc.)
My document uses a KOMA-script class and I use `biblatex`.

For this, I almost successfully adapted [Ulrike Fischer's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150176/64454) proposed for [How to split the bibliography alphabetically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150068/64454).

**Problem:** I use KOMA-script's `\marginline{<text>}` to print text in the margin. However, using this command at the beginning of a paragraph creates a margin-note... that is vertically aligned with the last line of previous paragraph. I thus need to use a `\raisebox{-\baselineskip}{<text>}` to properly align the marginnote, as shown below.

[image]

However, when I do the same in the bibliography, the margin-note is too much "de-raised":

[image]

**Question:** What is the right length to use for lowering the margin note? (and why is it different from `\baselineskip`?)

---

*Bonus question:* The current margin note is a letter with the same font size as the bibliography. I might want to increase its size. The question would be then: *How to vertically align the top of the margin note with the top of the relevant bibliographical entry?*
[image]

---

**MWEB**

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[%
        backend=biber,  %use biber as processing program
        bibstyle=authoryear, %how is LoR organized
        sorting=nyt,    %how are entries sorted in the LoR
    ]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
    \usepackage{filecontents}

%% Adaptation of Ulrike Fischer's solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150176/64454
\makeatletter
    \bibinitsep=1sp %to trigger blx@initsep
    \def\blx@initsep{%
        \blx@imc@iffieldundef{sortinit}
        {}
        {%
            \ifnum\c@instcount>\@ne
            \blx@imc@iffieldequals{sortinit}\blx@previnit
            {}
            {\marginline{\raisebox{-\baselineskip}{\sffamily\bfseries\printfield{sortinit}}}}
            \fi
            \global\let\blx@previnit\abx@field@sortinit%
        }%
    }
\makeatother
%% End of solution

    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
        @InBook{Azerty,
          author =   {Paul Azerty and Doe, John and Musterman, Erika},
          title =    {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.},
          chapter =      {Cras bibendum leo mauris, a ornare dolor rutrum egestas.},
          publisher =    {Donec consequat},
         Url                      = {http://dx.doi.org/10.007/1234567890987654321},
          year =     2010}


        @Book{Aqsdfgh,
          author =   {Paul Aqsdfgh and Musterman, John and Doe, Erika},
          title =    {Mauris bibendum diam lorem},
          publisher =    {Aliquam},
          year =     2010}

        @Article{Awxcvb,
          Title                    = {In euismod est eget urna euismod, cursus tincidunt odio dignissim.},
          Author                   = {Paul Awxcvb and Musterdoe, Jerika and Dann, Eron},
          Journal                  = {Maecenas pharetra},
          Year                     = {2010},
          Number                   = {13},
          Pages                    = {13--17},
          Publisher                = {Pellentesque},
          Url                      = {http://dx.doi.org/10.007/1234567890987654321},
          Volume                   = {17},
        }
        @InBook{Bzerty,
          author =   {Paul Bzerty and Doe, John and Musterman, Erika},
          title =    {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.},
          chapter =      {Cras bibendum leo mauris, a ornare dolor rutrum egestas.},
          publisher =    {Donec consequat},
          year =     2010}


        @Book{Bqsdfgh,
          author =   {Paul Bqsdfgh and Musterman, John and Doe, Erika},
          title =    {Mauris bibendum diam lorem},
          publisher =    {Aliquam},
          Url                      = {http://dx.doi.org/10.007/1234567890987654321},
          year =     2010}

        @Article{Bwxcvb,
          Title                    = {In euismod est eget urna euismod, cursus tincidunt odio dignissim.},
          Author                   = {Paul Bwxcvb and Musterdoe, Jerika and Dann, Eron},
          Journal                  = {Maecenas pharetra},
          Year                     = {2010},
          Number                   = {13},
          Pages                    = {13--17},
          Publisher                = {Pellentesque},
          Volume                   = {17},
        }
        @InBook{Dzerty,
          author =   {Paul Dzerty and Doe, John and Musterman, Erika},
          title =    {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.},
          chapter =      {Cras bibendum leo mauris, a ornare dolor rutrum egestas.},
          publisher =    {Donec consequat},
          year =     2010}


        @Book{Dqsdfgh,
          author =   {Paul Dqsdfgh and Musterman, John and Doe, Erika},
          title =    {Mauris bibendum diam lorem},
          publisher =    {Aliquam},
          year =     2010}

        @Article{Dwxcvb,
          Title                    = {In euismod est eget urna euismod, cursus tincidunt odio dignissim.},
          Author                   = {Paul Dwxcvb and Musterdoe, Jerika and Dann, Eron},
          Journal                  = {Maecenas pharetra},
          Year                     = {2010},
          Number                   = {13},
          Pages                    = {13--17},
          Publisher                = {Pellentesque},
          Volume                   = {17},
        }
        @InBook{Kzerty,
          author =   {Paul Kzerty and Doe, John and Musterman, Erika},
          title =    {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.},
          chapter =      {Cras bibendum leo mauris, a ornare dolor rutrum egestas.},
          publisher =    {Donec consequat},
          year =     2010}


        @Book{Zqsdfgh,
          author =   {Paul Dqsdfgh and Musterman, John and Doe, Erika},
          title =    {Mauris bibendum diam lorem},
          publisher =    {Aliquam},
          year =     2010}

        @Article{Zwxcvb,
          Title                    = {In euismod est eget urna euismod, cursus tincidunt odio dignissim.},
          Author                   = {Paul Zwxcvb and Musterdoe, Jerika and Dann, Eron},
          Journal                  = {Maecenas pharetra},
          Year                     = {2010},
          Number                   = {13},
          Pages                    = {13--17},
          Publisher                = {Pellentesque},
          Volume                   = {17},
        }
    \end{filecontents}

    \usepackage[francais]{babel}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]

    \marginline{Too high}
    \lipsum[2]


    \marginline{\raisebox{-\baselineskip}{Good}}
    \lipsum[3]

\newpage
    \nocite*
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to have to do with descenders in the previous line. I modified your example to not have letters with descenders in the bib entries, and things looked a bit nicer.

Comment: @moewe you mean removing letters like p, q, y, j, etc. ? (So basically, the *bottom* of the margin note would be aligned with the *bottom* of the entry's first line -- instead of being "baseline-aligned")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating on [clemens' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372070/64454), here is a solution for the "bonus question". Instead of baseline-aligning the bibliographical entry and the margin note (i.e., what is done in clemens' answer), *the top* of the margin note is now aligned with *the top* of the bibliographical entry. (More precisely, capital letters of the bibliographical entry are top-aligned with capital letters of the margin note.)

This notably enables to use initials with bigger (or smaller) font size than bibliographical entries' one.

[image]

The "trick" is to use a `raisebox` that drops the initial down so that it is top-aligned with the bibliographical entry's baseline, and then that lowers it up to the height of a bibliographical entry's capital letter.
(The only "problem" that can occur is when the initial is bigger than the entry that is at the bottom of the page – see "L" in the MWE – but in my opinion it is still acceptable)

---

```
\documentclass[twoside, a5, 12pt]{scrbook}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[%
        backend=biber,  %use biber as processing program
        bibstyle=authoryear, %how is LoR organized
        sorting=nyt,    %how are entries sorted in the LoR
    ]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
    \usepackage{filecontents}


%% Define font for bibliography and marginnote + some length calculation
    \usepackage{calc}
    \newcommand{\mybibliographyfont}{\normalfont}
    \newcommand{\mybibliographymagrinnotefont}{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}

    \newlength{\normallineheight}
        \setlength{\normallineheight}{\heightof{\mybibliographyfont M}}
    \newlength{\marginnoteheight}
        \setlength{\marginnoteheight}{\heightof{\mybibliographymagrinnotefont M}}

    %% Adaptation of Ulrike Fischer's solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150176/64454
    \makeatletter
        \bibinitsep=1sp %to trigger blx@initsep
        \def\blx@initsep{%
            \blx@imc@iffieldundef{sortinit}
            {}
            {%
                \ifnum\c@instcount>\@ne
                \blx@imc@iffieldequals{sortinit}\blx@previnit
                {}
                {\leavevmode\marginline{\raisebox{\dimexpr\normallineheight-\marginnoteheight\relax}{\mybibliographymagrinnotefont\printfield{sortinit}}}}% The objective is here to top-align capital letters of bib entry and the margin note
                \fi
                \global\let\blx@previnit\abx@field@sortinit%
            }%
        }
    \makeatother
%% End of solution

    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
        @InBook{Azerty,
          author =   {Paul Azerty and Doe, John and Musterman, Erika},
          title =    {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.},
          chapter =      {Cras bibendum leo mauris, a ornare dolor rutrum egestas.},
          publisher =    {Donec consequat},
         Url                      = {http://dx.doi.org/10.007/1234567890987654321},
          year =     2010}


        @Book{Aqsdfgh,
          author =   {Paul Aqsdfgh and Musterman, John and Doe, Erika},
          title =    {Mauris bibendum diam lorem},
          publisher =    {Aliquam},
          year =     2010}

        @Article{Awxcvb,
          Title                    = {In euismod est eget urna euismod, cursus tincidunt odio dignissim.},
          Author                   = {Paul Awxcvb and Musterdoe, Jerika and Dann, Eron},
          Journal                  = {Maecenas pharetra},
          Year                     = {2010},
          Number                   = {13},
          Pages                    = {13--17},
          Publisher                = {Pellentesque},
          Url                      = {http://dx.doi.org/10.007/1234567890987654321},
          Volume                   = {17},
        }
        @InBook{Bzerty,
          author =   {Paul Bzerty and Doe, John and Musterman, Erika},
          title =    {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.},
          chapter =      {Cras bibendum leo mauris, a ornare dolor rutrum egestas.},
          publisher =    {Donec consequat},
          year =     2010}


        @Book{Bqsdfgh,
          author =   {Paul Bqsdfgh and Musterman, John and Doe, Erika},
          title =    {Mauris bibendum diam lorem},
          publisher =    {Aliquam},
          Url                      = {http://dx.doi.org/10.007/1234567890987654321},
          year =     2010}

        @Article{Bwxcvb,
          Title                    = {In euismod est eget urna euismod, cursus tincidunt odio dignissim.},
          Author                   = {Paul Bwxcvb and Musterdoe, Jerika and Dann, Eron},
          Journal                  = {Maecenas pharetra},
          Year                     = {2010},
          Number                   = {13},
          Pages                    = {13--17},
          Publisher                = {Pellentesque},
          Volume                   = {17},
        }
        @InBook{Dzerty,
          author =   {Paul Dzerty and Doe, John and Musterman, Erika},
          title =    {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.},
          chapter =      {Cras bibendum leo mauris, a ornare dolor rutrum egestas.},
          publisher =    {Donec consequat},
          year =     2010}


        @Book{Dqsdfgh,
          author =   {Paul Dqsdfgh and Musterman, John and Doe, Erika},
          title =    {Mauris bibendum diam lorem},
          publisher =    {Aliquam},
          year =     2010}

        @Article{Dwxcvb,
          Title                    = {In euismod est eget urna euismod, cursus tincidunt odio dignissim.},
          Author                   = {Paul Dwxcvb and Musterdoe, Jerika and Dann, Eron},
          Journal                  = {Maecenas pharetra},
          Year                     = {2010},
          Number                   = {13},
          Pages                    = {13--17},
          Publisher                = {Pellentesque},
          Volume                   = {17},
        }
        @InBook{Kzerty,
          author =   {Paul Kzerty and Doe, John and Musterman, Erika},
          title =    {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.},
          chapter =      {Cras bibendum leo mauris, a ornare dolor rutrum egestas.},
          publisher =    {Donec consequat},
          year =     2010}
        @InBook{Kzerty2,
          author =   {Paul Kzerty and Doe, John and Musterman, Erika},
          title =    {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.},
          chapter =      {Cras bibendum leo mauris, a ornare dolor rutrum egestas.},
          publisher =    {Donec consequat},
          year =     2010}
        @InBook{Kzerty3,
          author =   {Paul Kzerty and Doe, John and Musterman, Erika},
          title =    {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.},
          chapter =      {Cras bibendum leo mauris, a ornare dolor rutrum egestas.},
          publisher =    {Donec consequat},
          year =     2010}   
        @InBook{Kzerty4,
          author =   {Paul Kzerty and Doe, John and Musterman, Erika},
          title =    {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.},
          chapter =      {Cras bibendum leo mauris, a ornare dolor rutrum egestas.},
          publisher =    {Donec consequat},
          year =     2010}    
        @InBook{Kzerty5,
          author =   {Paul Kzerty and Doe, John and Musterman, Erika},
          title =    {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.},
          chapter =      {Cras bibendum leo mauris, a ornare dolor rutrum egestas.},
          publisher =    {Donec consequat},
          year =     2010}                         
        @InBook{Lzerty,
          author =   {Paul Lzerty and Doe, John and Musterman, Erika},
          title =    {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.},
          chapter =      {Cras bibendum leo mauris, a ornare dolor rutrum egestas.},
          publisher =    {Donec consequat},
         Url                      = {http://dx.doi.org/10.007/1234567890987654321},
          year =     2010}
        @Book{Lqsdfgh,
          author =   {Paul Lqsdfgh and Musterman, John and Doe, Erika},
          title =    {Mauris bibendum diam lorem},
          year =     2010}

        @Article{Lwxcvb,
          Title                    = {In euismod est eget urna euismod, cursus tincidunt odio dignissim.},
          Author                   = {Paul Lwxcvb and Musterdoe, Jerika and Dann, Eron},
          Journal                  = {Maecenas pharetra},
          Year                     = {2010},
          Number                   = {13},
          Pages                    = {13--17},
          Publisher                = {Pellentesque},
          Url                      = {http://dx.doi.org/10.007/1234567890987654321},
          Volume                   = {17},
        }
        @Book{Zqsdfgh,
          author =   {Paul Dqsdfgh and Musterman, John and Doe, Erika},
          title =    {Mauris bibendum diam lorem},
          publisher =    {Aliquam},
          year =     2010}

        @Article{Zwxcvb,
          Title                    = {In euismod est eget urna euismod, cursus tincidunt odio dignissim.},
          Author                   = {Paul Zwxcvb and Musterdoe, Jerika and Dann, Eron},
          Journal                  = {Maecenas pharetra},
          Year                     = {2010},
          Number                   = {13},
          Pages                    = {13--17},
          Publisher                = {Pellentesque},
          Volume                   = {17},
        }
    \end{filecontents}

    \usepackage[francais]{babel}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \nocite*
    \mybibliographyfont
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't lower the entry in `\marginline` but add `\leavevmode` in front of it to make sure the paragraph started when the command starts doing its work:

```
\makeatletter
\bibinitsep=1sp %to trigger blx@initsep
\def\blx@initsep{%
  \blx@imc@iffieldundef{sortinit}
    {}
    {%
      \ifnum\c@instcount>\@ne
      \blx@imc@iffieldequals{sortinit}\blx@previnit
        {}
        {\leavevmode\marginline{\sffamily\bfseries\printfield{sortinit}}}%
      \fi
      \global\let\blx@previnit\abx@field@sortinit
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

and

```
\lipsum[1]

\leavevmode\marginline{Too high}
\lipsum[2]

\leavevmode\marginline{Good}
\lipsum[3]
```

[image]

[image]