# How to change the colon between index item and first page number?

Tags: indexing

Using the `memoir` class to typeset a book I have to change the delimiter between index items and the first page number.

The default looks like this:

```
Kant, Immanuel, 12, 13, 14, 15
Hegel, Georg Wilhelm Friedrich, 1,2,56
```

I would like to have it like this:

```
Kant, Immanuel 12, 13, 14, 15
Hegel, Georg Wilhelm Friedrich 1,2,56
```

How do I do this? Is this possible without using an extra package?

Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setmainlanguage[]{german}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[indentunit=0.4cm, hangindent=0.4cm, font=footnotesize,justific=raggedright]{idxlayout}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test, nothing else – Don't wast you time reading this!}
\Blindtext \index{Kant, Immanuel} \Blindtext \index{Hegel, Georg Wilhelm Friedrich} \Blindtext
\section{Test124}
\Blindtext \index{Kant, Immanuel} \index{Hegel, Georg Wilhelm Friedrich}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

As far as I found out, I have to use an index style file like `Indexstyle.ist` with the content:

```
delim_0 " "
```

But how to tell LaTeX to use it?

Comment: As always you have much greater chance of getting help if you post a minimal example that people can work from. BTW: this particular thing has nothing to do with `memoir`, but rather the indexing program you are using. As it so happens the `memoir` manual actually explain how one configure the common program `makeindex, see section 17.2.4

Comment: @daleif Maybe I am just not smart enough to understand it, but I did not found any hint in the`memoir` handbook, how to do this. So I added a minimal example.

Comment: @user5950 daleif said that `memoir` has no index capability, so you shouldn't tag the question with `memoir`: its manual gives an example configuration for `makeindex` / `makeidx`, but you should look at `idxlayout` manual for that kind of customization, since you use that package.

Comment: @Astrinus the documentation of `idxlayout` says that it can't change the delimiter. I thin I have to use a index style file, but I don't understand how to integrate it...

Comment: @user5950 see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17226/61789

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've already found what the contents of the `.ist` file must be.

So, create a file named `Indexstyle.ist` with the following contents:

```
delim_0 " "
```

To obtain your `.pdf` file containing the index like you want, run in the order (let's suppose your main file is `test.tex`):

> xelatex test
>
> makeindex -s Indexstyle.ist test
>
> xelatex test

You might have to repeat the last step twice. Obviously substitute xelatex with luatex or whatever engine you are using for it.

The result, as expected, will be:

[image]